# Swift empty Array of NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

in my CoreData project I created some NSManagedObjects, all with just a String attribute.

Now I want to initialize an empty array of NSManagedObject in my ViewController, so that I don't have to initialize all of my created objects
Later on, it should be filled with the NSManagedObject I selected before.

I got the error Message "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSManagedObject'
See the code below

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailChecklist: UIViewController {
var selectedList = String()
var selectedChecklisteArray = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

switch selectedList {
    case "makrolage":
       selectedChecklisteArray = [Makrolage]
    case "mikrolage":
        selectedChecklisteArray = [Mikrolage]
    default:
        print("No Data")
    }

}
```

I got the error message

> "Cannot assign value of type '[Makrolage].Type' to type
>   '[NSManagedObject]'"

Any idea to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `selectedChecklisteArray = [Makrolage]` `Makrolage` is a Type, the name of a class. It's not an instance.

Comment: You have already initialized the array here, `var selectedChecklisteArray = [NSManagedObject]()` so I don't see why you even need the code that gives you an error.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: I want to use it later in a tableView to get the output of the NSManagedObject, so I thought a global variable is useful.

Comment: Yes of course but I was talking about the `switch` code and not the declaration.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: Thank you, it works!